# How to check for which architecure U-boot image was built?

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, bootloader, u-boot

I'm working on adding certain feature to Uboot. I have accidentally bricked my device and am trying to determine what went wrong. My guess is that cross compilation went wrong, and the image produced was for some reason built for other than expected architecture (i.e. host architecture, instead of ARMv7). I tried to verify that by examining u-boot.bin:

1. file u-boot.bin but the only result I got was : 'data'. Not very useful.
2. After viewing 'u-boot.lds' for the architecture, I've got a hint:

   (..)
   OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
   (..)
3. Knowing that it should be ELF, I tried both readelf and objdump:

   > readelf -h u-boot.bin
   > readelf: Error: Not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start

   > objdump -f u-boot.bin
   > objdump: u-boot.bin: File format not recognized

I would appreciate any clues.

Comment: I do not expect it to be elf, but a raw binary image.  Your build system should have the elf version though.

Comment: Hello @old_timer. Where do I find elf version ?

Comment: OK, so ELF version is called just 'u-boot' without extension.

Comment: depends on the build system, often folks do this without an extension for linux and other (windows you would have .exe).  personally I explicitly use .elf or .bin, etc (for cross compiled embedded binaries)...but most folks do not.

Comment: I would acceot @old_timer answer, since you were first, but I think I cannot accept 'comment' as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U-Boot has a version command which cannot be disabled in the configuration. It writes a message like

```
=> version
U-Boot 2024.01-rc4 (Dec 06 2023 - 10:02:02 +0100)

riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-6ubuntu1) 13.2.0
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.41
```

These strings are in your u-boot.bin binary. You can find them with a hexadecimal editor like hexedit.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that one can just find ELF version of U-boot binary, and read the header using readelf -l.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).